# C: Problem with number 5 as length of array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, scanf

My friend made a program in C that gets 2 inputs. One being the length of the array and the other being the elements of the array. The code works fine, except for when the length of the array is 5. When the length of the array if 5, the first element becomes the same as the last element in the array (e.g. if the elements were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then it would be switched to 5, 2, 3, 4, 5). Here is the code he wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int length;

    printf("What is the length of your array?: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    length -= 1;
    int X[length], Y[length];

    printf("What are the elements of your array?: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &X[i]);
        Y[i] = X[i];
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", X[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", Y[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried searching the internet, but no matter what I do, I can't really wrap my head around what's happening.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `i <= length` This will cause an out of bounds access to your arrays. Try `i < length` instead

Comment: WIth this error it could happen that `X[length]` actually is location of `Y[0]` or the other way around. Accessing an array after its last element causes undefined behaviour and everything can happen.

Comment: Gerhardh `length` is not really the length of the array but the last index. See the code line `length -= 1;` It's not a good idea to give misleading names to variables.

Comment: @Elec1 If 'length' is the last index, the arrays are too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:
Indeed, reserve memory for 5, then use 1 less to iterate, as comments mention! You want 5, so it will go from 0 to 4. (1,2,3,4,5). -

So this:

```
scanf("%d", &length);
length -= 1;
int X[length], Y[length];
```

Should change to

```
scanf("%d", &length);    
int X[length], Y[length];    
length -= 1;
```

Or do not decrease length and in the for loop, use

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Playing before with my previous answer, using malloc makes this work, BUT, **having the right output does not necessarily mean it is correct:**

```
scanf("%d", &length);
length -=1;
//int X[length], Y[length];
int *X, *Y;
X,Y = (int *) malloc(length);
```

After that, with 5:

```
What is the length of your array?: 5
What are the elements of your array?: 
1
2
3
4
5

1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Allocating the wrong length is wrong regardless of whether it is done with `malloc` or a variable length array.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing length and offset. `length -= 1` will result in the allocation of `X` and `Y` to be too small, so when you iterate backwards through `Y` you’ll likely end up addressing the location of the last element of `X`.

But that’s very dependent on compiler/platform in terms of memory alignment. Anything where the offset exceeds the bounds of the array will lead to undefined behaviour.

If you move `length -= 1` after the declaration of `X` and `Y` it should work, but this isn’t generally good/preferred practice.

Alternatively remove `length -= 1` and change the comparison against length in the loops to be `i < lengths, and` int i = length - 1` in the last loop. This is generally the preferred style in C.

Comment: It is doubtful that “The reason you see it with 5 elements is likely to be due to 32 bit alignment in your compiler (4 bytes).” It is more likely due to the compiler aligning the arrays to 16-byte boundaries, due to stack alignment requirements, and four 32-bit `int` elements fitting in 16 bytes. Unless you have a basis for the claim 32-bit alignment is relevant, this answer would be better without it.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll read a bit more about the bit alignment that you were referring to but you were right to say that it works the same with 9 and 13. Would it be possible for you to give me some resources as to where I can learn more about this bit alignment.

Comment: @MachiBytes For the most part you shouldn't be concerning yourself with how a compiler positions the memory allocations, it's beyond the scope of the language itself, and you should be working within the known behaviours.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Apologies, I happened to be working on something using int8_t and had that in my head when I answered.  Given that we don't know what the target compiler/platform is, I think any speculation about alignment is moot.  I've removed mine so as not to add confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The size of array is not enough.

According to your code:

```
// Input length is 5
length -= 1; // The length is 4
int X[length], Y[length];
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)  // i -> 0 to 4, loop 5 times, but size of array is 4
    {
        scanf("%d", &X[i]);
        Y[i] = X[i];
    }
```

so swap two rows, it is correct.

```
int X[length], Y[length];
length -= 1;
```